# Sequence in inheritance with hibernate annotation and oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, inheritance, annotations, sequence

I have an inheritance

Abstract class A:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class A {

    public Integer id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Subclass B, that uses a sequence:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B
    extends A {

    private String descripction;

    @Override
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_TRANSACTIONID", sequenceName = "SEQ_TRANSACTION", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_TRANSACTIONID")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
    public String getDescripction() {
        return descripction;
    }

    public void setDescripction(String descripction) {
        this.descripction = descripction;
    }
}
```

And subclass C, that does not need a sequence:

```
public class C extends A {
}
```

The class B needs to generate a sequence but the class C doesn't.

I run the proyect with "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" in "create-drop". But SEQ_TRANSACTIONID is never created.

I've built this [test](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/52515066/hibernate-test-TRUNK.rar) so you can reproduce the error.

Help me please.....

Thanks in advance.